# 'Learning SQL: Master SQL Fundamentals' syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

Please I'm a newbie and i'm using the alain Beaulieu book 'Learning SQL' and on the first tutorial we need to add this function after creating the database 'bank'.

I have created it and typed the code but the shell returns the error after this code :

```
mysql> grant all privileges on bank.* to 'lrngsql'@'localhost' identified by 'xyz';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'xyz'' at line 1

I didn't find anyone speaking about this problem, so I hope someone could help

Comment: You do not have closing `'` (single quote) for user name.

Comment: In the future, before posting here, you should do what the error message tells you - check the documentation. It's easily found using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of MySQL you could use IDENTIFIED BY in a GRANT statement to change passwords or event create accounts. Newer versions do not have this option. Adding a user and granting it privileges are two separate things and therefore have to be done in two different statements.

Try

```
CREATE USER 'lrngsql'@'localhost' identified by 'xyz';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bank.* TO 'lrngsql'@'localhost';
```

For more information have a look at the documentation for [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) and [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html).